# JavaScript a function that receives pseudo-integer (i.e. 0100 or 03) and outputs correct integer

Tags: javascript, integer, decimal

Seems like it should be simple but I've been googling my rear-end off and thus far haven't been able to come up with a solution.  I think what sets this post apart from a lot of others I've seen is that my input is an integer though it may not be a proper JS number.

I'm trying to write a function that takes an **integer** (e.g. 0100, 010, 100, 0001) and then outputs the correct base 10 integer.

For example if the function receives 0100 what I want to put out is 100.

So,.. if I knew I was going to receive a 4-digit pseudo-integer say 0100 I could:

```
function getRealNumber(someNum){
    var realNum = parseInt(someNum, 16);
    return realNum;
}

getRealNumber(0100);
```

or:

```
function getRealNumber(someNum){
    var realNum = parseInt(someNum.toString(8));
    return realNum;
}

getRealNumber(0100);
```

I would return 100 but obviously if I received 100 that wouldn't work.

I thought I could first convert the input to a string and then parse it to an integer specifying base 10 like so:

```
function getRealNumber(someNum){
   var someNumString = someNum.toString();
   var realNum = parseInt(someNumString, 10);
   return realNum;
}

getRealNumber(0100);
```

but this results in 64.

So I think I'm stuck on determining the format of the received **integer** (i.e. hex, oct).

Thanks for the help and sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Will `someNum` always be a 1 prepended, and possibly followed by, 0's?

Comment: no,.. someNum could be 0250, 0371, 04, 040, 500, 623 etc,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the pseudo-integer as a string. If you enter a numeric literal, it's parsed by the Javascript compiler into a number before `parseInt()` ever gets called, and the Javascript compiler treats numbers that begin with `0` as octal. So it should be:

```js
function getRealNumber(someNum){
    var realNum = parseInt(someNum, 10);
    return realNum;
}

console.log(getRealNumber('0100'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer literals starting with a `0` are considered base-8 or octal numbers, in the same way that integers starting with `0x` are considered base-16 or hexadecimal. I don't know if the same happens for integers inside strings.

```
01 === 1
010 === 8
0100 === 64
...
```

Try entering `0109`. You should get an error -9 is not a valid octal digit-. But to be honest I have never ever worked with octal numbers.